# Error while using simple login in ember?

Tags: ember.js

I am a newbie to Ember and as a part of learning i was trying to set up the login form from one tutorial but it doesnot seem to be working.
**Error: Invalid Path---Thats the Error i am getting in login method**

I want to see if the password is okay then connect login template else kick the user to '/'.?

**Html file**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="login">
        {{message}} <br>
        E-Mail {{view Ember.TextField target="controller" valueBinding= controller.email}} <br />
        Password {{view Ember.TextField target="controller" valueBinding= controller.password}} <br />
        <button {{action login}}>Login</button>
    </script>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="loggedin">
        Welcome to Our Site !
    </script>
```

**JS File**

```
 App.LoginController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
email :null,
password :null,
message :null,

login : function() {
    var loginCreds = this.getProperties('email','password');
    if (loginCreds.password === 'admin') {
        this.set('isAuthenticated',true);
        console.log(isAuthenticated);
        this.get('target').send('isAuthenticated');

    }
    else{
        this.set('message','Invalid password');
        this.set('isAuthenticated',false);
        console.log(isAuthenticated);
        this.get('target').send('isAuthenticated');

    }

}
    });

    App.LoginRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
isAuthenticated : function(router) {
    router.transitionTo('loggedin');
},
connectOutlets: function(router) {
    if (!router.get('loginController.isAuthenticated')) {
        router.transitionTo('/');
    }
    router.get('loginController').connectOutlet('loggedin');
    },
    });
```

Comment: can u atleast post the stacktrace generated from EmberJS?

Comment: i think problem may be u didnt map the path u are giving in the browser...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think problem may be u didnt map the path u are giving in the browser.You should map the path like this

```
App.Router.map(function () {
    this.route('login');
});
```

then in the url u can add `#login`

Comment: Sorry i didnot post the whole code but i did map the path `App.Router.map(function() {
 this.route("index");
 this.route("search");
 this.route("toggle");
 this.route("login");

});
`